# How can I prove that $16 \lt {1+\frac1{\sqrt2}+\frac1{\sqrt3}+\cdots+\frac1{\sqrt{80}}<18}$?

Tags: inequality, summation, radicals

What i want to prove is this
$$16 \lt {1+\frac1{\sqrt2}+\frac1{\sqrt3}+\cdots+\frac1{\sqrt{80}}<18}$$

I haven't encountered any problem of this kind before, how do we proceed?

Making approximations dosen't seem feasible, so all the suggestions are welcome.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange.  Did you mean $< 18$?

Comment: I'd try to approximate the sum by an integral.

Comment: @J.W.Tanner, yes, that was a typo

Comment: @AnginaSeng, i haven't been introduced to calculus yet

Comment: If you haven't been introduced to calculus yet, then why do you need to solve this exercise?

Comment: @DietrichBurde, i ment crude approximations, like taking $\sqrt80=9$

Comment: I think the idea is in the following. Try to show by induction, that, starting from some $n$, $2(\sqrt{n}-1) <1+\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}+...+\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}< 2 \sqrt{n}$. It should be something like that. However I'm not sure, that why i'm writing it as a comment.

Comment: There are interesting ideas in this post. https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2149448/399263  In particular you can use $\sum \frac 1{\sqrt{k}}>2(\sqrt{n+1}-1)=16$ for $n=80$ using telescoping sum.

Comment: There is at least [this old thread](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/896259/11619).

Comment: Also, I recommend that you study the tips in our [How to ask a good question?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9959/11619) thread. Your question is a bit lacking in context.

Comment: Also [AOPS](https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c6h321619p1727392).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let's look at the telescoping sum
$$S=(\sqrt2-1)+(\sqrt3-\sqrt2)+(\sqrt4-\sqrt3)+\cdots+(\sqrt{81}-\sqrt{80})=9-1=8.$$
Then
$$S=\sum_{n=1}^{80}(\sqrt{n+1}-\sqrt n)=\sum_{n=1}^{80}\frac1{\sqrt{n+1}+\sqrt n}.$$
So
$$S<\sum_{n=1}^{80}\frac1{2\sqrt n}$$
so
$$\sum_{n=1}^{80}\frac1{\sqrt n}>2S=16.$$
Also
$$S>\sum_{n=1}^{80}\frac1{2\sqrt{n+1}}$$
so that
$$\sum_{n=1}^{80}\frac1{\sqrt{n+1}}<2S=16.$$
But
$$\sum_{n=1}^{80}\frac1{\sqrt n}
=\sum_{n=1}^{80}\frac1{\sqrt{n+1}}+1-\frac19$$
and we get
$$\sum_{n=1}^{80}\frac1{\sqrt n}<17-\frac19.$$

Comment: More generally, $$2(\sqrt{b+1}-\sqrt a)\le\sum_{n=a}^b\frac1{\sqrt{n}}\le2(\sqrt{b+1}-\sqrt a)+\frac1{\sqrt a}-\frac1{\sqrt{b+1}}.$$

Answer (score 5):

if we have $g(x) > 0$ but $g'(x) < 0,$  then
$$ \int_a^{b+1} \; g(x) \;  dx \;  < \; \sum_{j=a}^b \;  g(j) \; < \; \int_{a-1}^b \;  g(x) \; dx   $$

for you $g(x) = \frac{1}{\sqrt x}$  which is integrable at the origin, so we can take $a=1$ and $b=80$

Comment: The OP does not know this: $\displaystyle\int$...

Comment: @YvesDaoust  you seem to be correct. I like Dietrich's question.

Answer (score 4):

This can be done using a theorem

$$2(\sqrt{n+1}-{n}) \lt \frac1 {\sqrt n}\lt 2(\sqrt n -\sqrt {n-1
}) $$

And to prove it, just rationalise the numerator on RHS and LHS